# Inline-block element drops on hover effect?

Tags: css, css-animations, mousehover

I'm trying to configure an extremely basic animation effect in which hovering over a div animates a `form` element alongside it from 0 to 100% `width` using a CSS transition. [Here is a fiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/8bbop1w5/). I'm experiencing two issues: first, in this case, the `<p>` element and `<form>` elements are not lining up vertically, despite being set to `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`. Secondly, on hover in widening the `form` element to 100%, it's dropping below the `<p>` element; does anyone know what's going on here?

```css
    #wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #wrapper p {
        font-size: 16px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #wrapper:hover form#access {
        width: 100%;
    }
    form#access {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
        -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    form#access input {
        font-size: 18px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
        max-width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
      <p>Enter code:</p>
      <form id="access">
        <input placeholder="code" id="access-code" name="access-code" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: How about something a little different like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8bbop1w5/14/

Comment: If you need the form to remain above the `p` element it should be placed before it. The `margin` on `p` is preventing the vertical alignment, I noticed that you don't have `vertical-align` declared on your `#access` either. If you need these elements to remain along side each other, they should be displayed as `inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your form to 100% width on hover, which would take the entire width of its parent.
You can either lower that percentage so that it fits on a single line with the paragraph, or simply add this to #wrapper:

```
    white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set `form#access` to `100%` which needs the whole width of the `#wrapper container`.

This should work instead:

```
#wrapper:hover form#access {
    width: 100px;
}
```

---

Also consider using `display: inline-flex` on the wrapper so you don't need to set `display: inline-block` and it's easier to center both elements.

I updated your [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8bbop1w5/15/)